# Is there any ASCII character that acts as placeholder without effect?

Tags: c, ascii

As the Question already tells:

I want to know, is there a ASCII character which will be treat by C in/out without any effect?

As example when I write (Where `Y` would represent this character)

```
printf ("abcYdYfg");
```

the output should be:

> abcdfg

And this control character also shall have no effect on any standard memory or string operating functions.

Is there any ASCII character coming up with this requirements?

Comment: Well, try a test and print them all out.

Comment: Doesn't help that much, as there could be side effects which I dont notice now but will later break something in some mem or string operations.

Comment: I'm not sure there is one, but perhaps you can describe the underlying problem you're trying to solve - it might have a better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no effect on any standard memory or string operating functions'?  Any control character that isn't given a backslash-letter escape sequence might be usable, other than `'\0'`.

Comment: I have a String where I want to replace in some cases 3 chars by a single char, but as the string could be pretty big and is read only 1 time anyway. I wouldn't like to make the chars move up to fill the empty fields as this would take more time as just putting in some characters whcih will jsut be ignored. But I'm in fear of some effects, I'm not expecting, when I put that string to the stdo.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis I tryed to describe my prblem in the comment above.

Comment: @Zaibis: You just need to call `memmove`. Writing a magical character can't get you out of having to do this.

Comment: The character will still up in a file if you redirect stdout. This whole affair sounds like asking for trouble if you ask me.

Comment: @Zaibis: Because otherwise your data will be corrupt, even if you don't *see* the corruption. For example, `strstr(s, "cde")` would fail to find `"cde"` in your example string because it's not there, even if it looks like it's there. Your ugly hypothetical invisible character is in the middle.

Comment: Hmmmm ok I agree to that, But in my special case even that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use `0x1d`, `0x1e`, `0x1f`, those are the group, record and unit separators. They are intended for exactly what you are trying to do. See [ASCII, the history](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/ascii-characters.html)

That being said, I don't think you want to use special characters in this way, instead use [memmove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) as @R suggests in the comments to you question.

Comment: Do I understand it right, that they are just thought for kind of "meta information"? and do not request any operation?

Comment: Indeed, only `0x0` has any meaning to the usual `C`-functions. With regards to printing that of course will always come down to your shell's implementation, and it not doing anything stupid.

Comment: 0x0a 0x0b 0x0c 0x0d have effect to the output too don't they? Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: `0x9`, `0xa`, `0xb` `0xc` and `0xd` will have an effect, as they are spacing characters. But I didn't mention them in my answer.

Comment: Ah ok, and all others will ahve no effect for stdio in plain C? thats awesome, thanks :)

Comment: No, the three I mentioned in the answer, will probably not be displayed, this of course depends on your shells implementation of them, but if the shell handles them as they are intended, then it will just ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends largely on what you mean by "no effect". In terms of the contents written into a file/stream/device, there is no such thing. Every character written advances the file position by one byte/character or transmits a character over the line. However, if you're talking about writing to an interactive display device (terminal), there are characters which will not move the cursor. The most obvious example is the NUL character (`'\0'`). You cannot embed it in a C string (because it terminates the string) but you could print it using `%c` and an argument 0 with `printf` or via `putc` or `fwrite`, etc.